# Why 'download' attribute doesnt work in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, safari

This is my code:

```
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = *link_to_file*;
a.download = 'myFileName.mp4';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

In all browsers file downloaded with name myFileName.mp4
But in Safari 12 'download' attribute doesn't work. Why it can happens?
And how to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: "But in Safari 12 'download' attribute doesn't work." — What do you mean by "[doesn't work](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)"? Does the video open in the browser window instead?

Comment: can you plz try this
`<button type="submit" onclick="window.open('file.mp4')">Download</button>`

Download attribute not works for all browsers.

Comment: "In all browsers file downloaded with name myFileName.mp4 " — That's odd, I'd expect this code to error with something like `ReferenceError: myFileName is undefined`

Comment: @AzeemAslam — See Pete's comment. Safari 12 supports the download attribute.